# Why would I want to use itertools.islice instead of normal list slicing?

Tags: python, list, iterator

It seems to me that many functions in the `itertools` module have easier equivalents. For example, as far as I can tell, `itertools.islice(range(10),2,5)` does the same thing as `range(10)[2:5]`, and `itertools.chain([1,2,3],[4,5,6])` does the same thing as `[1,2,3]+[4,5,6]`. The main documentation page mentions speed advantages, but are there any reasons to choose itertools besides this?

Comment: They don't really do the same thing. itertools.islice(), range() and itertools.chain() return different objects. Finally these objects behave the same but in your case I would consider comparing the byte code if speed matters.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To address the two examples you brought up:

```
import itertools


data1 = range(10)

# This creates a NEW list
data1[2:5]

# This creates an iterator that iterates over the EXISTING list
itertools.islice(data1, 2, 5)


data2 = [1, 2, 3]
data3 = [4, 5, 6]

# This creates a NEW list
data2 + data3

# This creates an iterator that iterates over the EXISTING lists
itertools.chain(data2, data3)
```

There are many reasons why you'd want to use iterators instead of the other methods. If the lists are very large, it could be a problem to create a new list containing a large sub-list, or especially create a list that has a copy of two other lists. Using `islice()` or `chain()` allows you to iterate over the list(s) in the way you want, without having to use more memory or computation to create the new lists. Also, as [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu) mentioned, you can't use bracket slicing or addition with iterators.

I hope that's enough of an answer; there are plenty of other answers and other resources explaining why iterators are awesome, so I don't want to repeat all of that information here.

Comment: Worth mentioning too that `itertools.chain` can take many arguments to chain together an arbitrary number of lists, whereas you can't do that with the `+` operator. E.g. `itertools.chain(*arbitrary_list_of_lists)`

Comment: @veggie1, you can `+` multiple lists. Still better to use `itertools.chain()` though, or build a list with `list.extend()` if you need to store it.

Comment: you *can*, but not for an arbitrary or unknown number of lists unless you use a loop with `operator.add`

Comment: @veggie1, well.. `sum(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]), [])`. Or, `sum(arbitrary_list_of_lists, [])`. :D

Comment: @veggie1, good point though, I see what you meant. I'm not really being stubborn :P.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize you could do that with `sum`. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

`itertools.islice` can slice [iterators](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator).
Indexing only works with [sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-sequence).
For example,

```
In [64]: iterator = (x**2 for x in range(10))

In [65]: list(IT.islice(iterator, 2, 5))
Out[65]: [4, 9, 16]

In [66]: iterator[2:5]
TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Also, even for lists, `islice` doesn't create a new list, whereas regular list slicing does.

Comment: @BrenBarn On the other hand, `islice` will iterate through `0..start` elements in the list, whereas list slicing skips those and goes directly to `start`. Perhaps one alternative is `(xs[i] for i in range(start, stop))`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with vanilla python

```
In [64]: iterator = (x**2 for x in range(10))

In [65]: [x for i, x in enumerate(iterator) if i>=2 and i<5]
Out[65]: [4, 9, 16]
```