# Does chunking via itertools vs straight python buy you anything extra?

Tags: python, python-itertools, readability

I came across [two different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) to split an `iterable` into "chunks" (more than 1 item).

[One method uses `itertools`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434411/52074):

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

[the other method is straight python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434328/52074):

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))
```

**Does the itertools implementation buy you anything "extra"?**

Where "extra" would be, maybe faster or more flexible or safer.

I ask because the itertools implementation shown here is definitely NOT more readable/intuitive IMO.

Comment: I agree that the iterable approach looks a bit magic-y, but it can be implemented in a more readable way as well. Both approaches, iterators and slices, can be written in many ways, so readability isn't really a factor imo

Comment: You can also use: `def chunker(iterable, size): yield from iter(lambda it=iter(iterable): list(islice(it, size)), [])`...

Comment: @unutbu yup and will work nicely prior to `yield from` as well... Only noticeable difference is that `inspect.isgenerator` fails for `iter`... but *shrugs*... 6 and half a dozen and all that...

Comment: @Felk I think "magic-y" is an euphemism. To cite the docs for the abused list initialisation through a multiplier: "_they are referenced multiple times. This often haunts new Python programmers_". The bad thing in this is that the nearly identical `[iter(iterable) for _ in range(n)]` has different effects.

Comment: Related: [Why would I want to use itertools.islice instead of normal list slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32172612/190597).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grouper` can be used with *any* [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) -- including generators and infinite iterators.
`chunker` can only be used with [sequences](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-sequence) -- iterables whose length is knowable in advance.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))

x = (i**2 for i in range(5))

print(list(grouper(x, 3)))
# [(0, 1, 4), (9, 16, None)]

print(list(chunker(x, 3)))
# TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1):

The two functions aren't equivalent. There are several differences:

- Your `grouper` will work for any iterable including iterators and generators, while `chunker` requires sequences that support indexing (the `[...]`).

  ```
  >>> it = lambda : (i for i in range(6))  # creates a generator when called
  >>> list(grouper(it(), 3))
  [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)]
  >>> list(chunker(it(), 3))
  TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
  ```

  Note that the other answer already mentioned this!
- In case the chunksize isn't a divisor of the length the `chunker`s last element will be smaller than the chunksize. OTOH the `grouper` will fill it with some fillvalue. Also `chunker` will return the same type as the original, while `grouper` will return `tuple`s:

  ```
  >>> list(grouper([1,2,3,4,5], 3))
  [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, None)]
  >>> list(chunker([1,2,3,4,5], 3))
  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
  ```
- `grouper` uses the high-performance built-ins `iter` and `zip_longest`. These will be very fast. At the expense of readability. However this can make it much faster than `chunker`:

  ```
  l = list(range(10000))
  %timeit list(grouper(l, 10))
  # 320 µs ± 6.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  %timeit list(chunker(l, 10))
  # 1.22 ms ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
  ```

So `grouper` is a faster and more general approach than `chunker`. However depending on the case it could be more useful to use `chunker`, for example if you don't like the "fill"-part or want to preserve the type of the "chunks".