# Question about returning combination N taken K

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to list all combination of `k` length in `a` list 1 to `n`. I found this neat code that returns all the combinations.

```
def combs(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return [[]]
    cs = []
    for c in combs(a[1:]):
        cs += [c, c+[a[0]]]
    return cs
```

Is there a way I could modify this so that I could give a limit of the length of list it returns?

If:

```
k = 3
n = 5
```

it will only return combinations of length 3 from:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

hence the return would be:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

I am not allowed to use any import as a restriction

Comment: can you provide an example of the expected output? is the behavior of `combs` already what you want but with a `break` condition? take a look at [this question with itertools.islice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32172612/6692898)

Comment: use `itertools.combinations`

Comment: if I were to give n = 3 and k = 2, then the lst = [1, 2, 3] and all possible combination would be [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]].

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to use itertools as part of a restriction

Answer (score 0):

I added a new parameter `k`.

Note the line:

```py
if len(c) >= k: return cs
```

This will break the loop early if it the array is greater than `k`.

```py
def combs(a, k, l=0):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return [[]]
    cs = []
    for c in combs(a[1:], k, l+1):
        cs += [c, c+[a[0]]]
    if l == 0:
        css = []
        for i in cs:
            if len(i) == k:
                css += [i]
        return css
    return cs


print(combs([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3))
```

Hence, when `k == 3`, the code returns the following:

```
[[3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1], [4, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1], [5, 3, 1], [5, 3, 2], [5, 4, 1], [5, 4, 2], [5, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you! this made the code run faster since it negates all other combination greater than k. However, is there a way it can return only size of 3? [[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[4,3,1]] like that?

Comment: @Winny Ok, I just edited the answer so that it returns `[[3,2,1],[4,2,1],[4,3,1]]`. It basically just filters out all the smaller ones.